# VBA Excel, VLookup for multiple values count

Tags: vba, excel

I have One excel file.

```
 EmployeeName                   Expenses
 Ajay                                      2000
 Vijay                                     1000
 Ajay                                      1500
 Vijay                                     500
```

I want to count the number of expenses for each employee. I can get the first occurance of the Expenses of the given employee with Vlookup like this

```
sExpense = XLApplication.VLookup("Ajay", Range("A1:B99"), 2, False)
```

But how Can I find the sum of all expenses from a given Employee.

Comment: you can always write a custom function to accomplish the task, or you have to use excel functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
  Dim sExpense As String
  Dim range1 As Range
  Dim sumRange As Range

  Set range1 = Range("A2:A5")
  Set sumRange = Range("b2:b5")

  sExpense = Me.Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(range1, "Ajay", sumRange)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the SUMIF function provided by excel:

For example

```
C6=SUMIF(A:A,"Vijay",B:B)
```

It look through the range in A:A (column A) for any cell match "Ajay" and sum their total in Column B

[image]